# How to sort only part of multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I want to highlight, for example, rows 5-15 across columns C, D, and E, and sort only that block in ascending order by one of the columns.  The trick is that I want all included columns to follow suit so that the data maintains integrity within rows.

Usually when you sort ascending or sort descending it's by highlighting an entire column, and you're given an option to expand the selection, which would sort your entire spreadsheet based on the new order.

Am I able to sort only a block, without choosing the entire column?

Comment: Try highlighting those 3 columns and sort by the required column (click the required column first when selecting), if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You must apply the sort to the entire row of data that you are sorting for it to maintain integrity. So you can select rows 5-15 and select filter, then just filter by c d or e.

Comment: You only need the entire row if the other columns are associated with what's in that block.  If the other columns are unrelated, you only need to highlight the block, but you do need to highlight everything that requires maintaining integrity.  You can sort the block by what ever column you want, or even several columns in a specified order (the sort columns must be included in the selection).

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found is to cut and paste the highlighted portion to a new sheet and then sort it over there, once sorted copy/cut and paste it back to the original location.

Comment: This is only true if your data set is formatted as a Table.  Excel allows sorting of selections inside of a range but will always sort an entire table.  Also, it would likely be simpler to convert the table to a range, sort the selection, and reformat as a table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can sort only a block. Just highlight the rows you want sorted, and it will sort only that area.

Note that if you receive this message:
[image]
then you have not selected all the *columns* in your table. As long as you don't get that message, then your sort will go as expected.

Comment: Sean, thanks for the comment.  I think that won't work because if I include more than one column in that block, Excel won't do anything.  Actually, I may have found a solution--Kingsoft office will sort the block by the left-hand column in that situation.  Do you know of an office feature that will do the same thing?

Comment: Sadly, this solution doesn't appear valid in Office 2010 v 14

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to do this with a Microsoft Office Application. And if it can be, which one? If that is correct, based on your last entry, you can accomplish the task using MS Excel 2010 by doing the following:

1. Select cells C5:D15
2. Using Excel 2010, click on "Home" in the menu bar
3. Click in the "Editing" tab, on "Sort & Filter"
4. Select "Custom Sort"
5. Uncheck the box "My data has headers"
6. Sort By: Column C
7. Sort On: Values
8. Order: A to Z
9. Click OK

Should you need to Sort Left to Right, instead of Top to Bottom, click the "Options.." button in the dialog box, to make that selection.

I have tested this with various numbers/data in all bordering rows and columns with success. And with only the data in the selected cells,rows,columns being sorted.  All other data remained unchanged.

Comment: The title of the question says 'Excel' and there is a "Microsoft-excel" tag on the question.  Why were you in any doubt about which application was to be used?

Answer (score 0):

In my current experience, it is a question of whether a data table is defined as a Table (Insert-> Table) or not. If it is a Table, this formatting must be canceled i.e. converted to a range (e.g. "To remove table" at https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/tables/1/), then only parts of it can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is as follows: You've highlighted rows 5-15 across columns C-E – which creates your "highlighted block" – and you only want to sort **that** block (ignoring all the other rows and columns) in ascending order by one of the columns.

What you can do is insert a blank row just above row 5 and another blank row just after row 15. This should create a separated "block". Then, just select all the cells in whichever column you want to sort your data, from the top of your newly created block all the way to the end of your newly created block.

Then (on the latest version of Excel; I'm running version 2202), you can do the usual sort by ascending or descending: From the ribbon bar: `Home` → under the `Editing` section → click on `Sort & Filter`. Then choose either `Sort Smallest to Largest` or `Sort Largest to Smallest`. All the data in your block should now be sorted, maintaining data integrity within rows. Everything else outside that block should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Please note,, the area/range to SORT is AL4:AO8.
2. I've just highlighted it for easy identification.
3. Select AL4:AO8.
4. Now from HOME Tab, hit SORT & FILTER then CUSTOM SORT.

[image]

1. Set/Select SORT by Column, Value & Order as shown is Screen Short.
2. Finish with Ok.

[image]

**N.B.**

*Data range & Sorting Parameters are editable/adjustable.*